# No puedo abrir KB

Tags: genexus

Copié una KB de un equipo a otro y al intentar abrir e importar la Base de Datos al SQLServer me da el siguiente error:

**AuthenticationFailed(Artech.Architecture.Common)**

No importa si abro el .gxw o abro el .mdf, cuando me pide importar la base de datos me da ese error.

¿Alguna idea de que pueda ser el error?

Estoy usando mi usuario de Windows para loguearme en SQLServer, le asigné todos los permisos para ver si era algo de eso, pero tampoco funcionó.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.